# Background Image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried out the following code and for some reason my background image doesn't take up the whole page and it only covers the navigation bar. What should I change in the following code? Also how can I make the navigation bar span the whole width of the web page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Static Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="background-image:url('tp.jpg');">
<div class="bs-example">
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TNP</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Companies<b class="caret"></b></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Rakuten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Morgan Stanley</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TCS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nvidia</a></li>
            </ul>
             </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Student <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `.container` get height of `nav`. You must add `height:100%` to `.container` to take rest of page.

Comment: And add `background-size: cover;` to `.container` to get image cover it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the class `container-fluid` instead of `container` to make it use entire width.

And the container needs to be given a **height**. Currently it will simply grow as you will add more elements inside it.

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dorfxeq9/).

Comment: How can I add height to current code? Can I just add the height attribute to the line where I have specified the background url?

Comment: Yes you can add it there. You can add the image inside body also, if you dont want to specify height to the container. There are lots of ways. Just play with a couple of them, you will hit by each one's pros and cons.